# Android Studio resource not found after duplicate

Tags: android, resources, duplicates

I have been trying all the different solutions I found on other posts for this issue and none of them worked. I'm trying to duplicate a project in Android Studio. The original project is an Eclipse project that I imported in AS and it's working well. To duplicate it, I copy-paste the folder of the project in the same folder and then I import it from AS. I already tried it several time for other projects and it usually works fine. But there, I've got 120 errors such as:
"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined".

I already tried to clean, rebuild the project, sync build, uncheck build-in-process in settings, invalidate cache/restart, refactor the package name... do you have any other ideas or procedures? It seems the R class is not built but there is no obvious mistakes in my xml that I didn't change from the original project and Manifest seems fine.

Comment: pay attention to the package name.. classes may try to import or use functions that are sitting in other packages..
also try to copy from the "com" folder into your java folder on android studio..

Comment: Package names are correct. The errors are coming from xml files that are specific to my project:
\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldrtl-v23\values-ldrtl-v23.xml
app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue: I was using resources from a more recent API than the one I was using to compile. After changing compilerVersion in build to 23 instead of 16, it worked fine. BUT since I wanted to compile with version 16 because I'm using NDK, I rechanged the compilerVersion to 23 afterward and it's still working.